# Error with Blazor WebAssembly Project after upgrade to net5.0

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

After following the upgrade instructions here;

[Migrate Core 3.1 to 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

On my Blazor WebAssembly project (running as .Server project, .Shared project and .Client project).

Everything seems to have gone well apart from when I reference another project in the solution. I want the client side to reference the .Shared and another class library (this was working with 3.1 prior). I get the following error;

> Error BLAZORSDK1001   The project references the ASP.NET Core shared
> framework, which is not supported by Blazor WebAssembly apps. Remove
> the framework reference if directly referenced, or the package
> reference that adds the framework reference.

My `Client.csproj` has the following;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.6" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="blazor.extensions.logging" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Bootstrap" Version="0.9.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Components" Version="0.9.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.DataGrid" Version="0.9.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" Version="0.9.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Blazorise.Sidebar" Version="0.9.3.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Toolbelt.Blazor.HttpClientInterceptor" Version="9.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\tinymce\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- When publishing, swap service-worker.published.js in place of service-worker.js -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\service-worker.js" />
    <Content Update="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" Link="wwwroot\service-worker.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Blazor.Shared\Blazor.Shared.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core.Search\Core.Search.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\favicon.ico">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\manifest.json">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\service-worker.js">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

and the `.csproj` of the referenced projects are;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="fluentvalidation.aspnetcore" Version="8.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.aspnetcore.identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.identitymodel.tokens" Version="6.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is caused by the fluentvalidation.aspnetcore package.  The current release of this package contains references to the ASP.NET Core shared framework.  These references are required for certain server-side features of FluentValidation such as when you are implementing a validator interceptor.

If you are trying to use the same validator for both your WASM client and your ASP.NET server project, and if you implement one of those features like the IValidatorInterceptor interface, then your shared validator will have to reference the fluentvalidation.aspnetcore package which Blazor will not work with.

Rather than use the integrated validation in your Startup.cs class where you add fluentvalidation to your MVC controllers, you'll have to instantiate a different validator in the Controller action and call the Validate method on the object you're validating to get around this issue.

At this point, Blazor client-side validation is not integrated into the official FluentValidation package, but rather entails use of separate packages as indicated in the FluentValidation documentation.

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/blazor.html

I'm not sure how easy it will be to exclude the ASP.NET reference if one is using Blazor, but at least by manually validating the incoming object you have a work-around.